# ionic2+ how to cache page so that i can navigate to certain page with the page cached

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, ionic-view

**BG**: I got 2 page and want to switch to each other every 60 seconds.
now i am using push/pop to do the job. when i push the second page it will create a new one and the page would flicker which had a bad user experience. when i pop to the first page. it works just fine.

**Q**: how can i navigate to certain page with the page cached. and i've searched the [NavController](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavController/)
and i did not find any api could help.

thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

You can use `nav.push('AboutPage')` for pusing your previous page to cache. Use `nav.pop()` to clear top cache value and go back to previous page. User `nav.setRoot('AboutPage')` to clear the cache and start from begining.

Comment: after i push `AboutPage` to the cache and i go back to the previous page using`pop()` . but i did want to go to `AboutPage` again. so i want to keep AboutPage in cache.what should i do? thanks.

Comment: Use. nav.push(PageName). It wont delete the aboutpage from cache... On load after every 60 seconds navigate to another page.

Comment: or You can override on backpress which will allow you to override backpress functionality.

Comment: export class MyPage {
  @ViewChild(Navbar) navBar: Navbar;
  constructor(private navController: NavController){}
  ionViewDidLoad() {
    this.navBar.backButtonClick = (e:UIEvent)=>{
     // todo something
     this.navController.pop();
    }
  }

Comment: thanks for your reply @rashmi ranjan. I am using `nav.push('AboutPage')`to `AboutPage` at HomePage .  after few seconds i using `nav.pop()` nav back to HomePage. **and  `AboutPage` would not cached** . after few seconds  i am using  `nav.push('AboutPage')` to `AboutPage` again. which would create a new one. this is what i am doing:  `HomePage -(by push)-> AboutPage -(by pop)-> HomePage -(by push)-(by pop)-> AboutPage -->...`

Comment: All what i want is cache `AboutPage`  like `HomePage` do. Look forward to your reply. thanks

Comment: then use push in aboutpage also. it will cache aboutpage also. whatever you will push it will store in cache. nav.push(anything) it will store that in cache like a queue.

Comment: sorry for reply so late. apparently i known that *push* would cache the `AboutPage`. like you said it just like queue. but how can i still cache the page after i call `pop()` to nav back to `HomePage`. or i just should not call `pop()` and using some other way instead?

Comment: Pop method wont keep that page in queue.. you have to use push method. Ex about> pop() (it will not keep about in queue but it will navigate to home page). if you want to do the same using push you have to use homepage > push(about). it will navigate you to  about page. you have to use your own login. there is no harm in using push method to navigate. but using pop u wont be able to put it in cache.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this example helps to visualize this:

*1. Initial state after startup:*

```
[HomePage]
```

*2. State after nav.push('AboutPage'):*

```
 [HomePage, AboutPage]

 ^^^^^^^^
 cached
```

*3. State if you use the navbar to navigate back or pop():*

```
[HomePage] // The cached instance is used so ionViewDidLoad() is not called
```

*4. State if you use .push('HomePage') after the second step:*

```
[HomePage, AboutPage, HomePage] // a new instance is created so ionViewDidLoad() is called
 ^^^^^^^^  ^^^^^^^^^
  cached    cached
```

Ionic 2.x are use this process and its a standard process.

inspired form [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46970463/ionic-pages-not-cached)

Comment: If i want to do jobs like this `HomePage --> AboutPage --> HomePage  --> AboutPage -->...`. how can i keep HomePage and AboutPage both in cache？ thanks

Comment: In ionviewwillleave function you just you clear the cache by using .pop()

Comment: Is there any way to not clear the cache? cause that was not what i want